# pass dynamic value to Url.Action in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

This is a part of my view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ForgotPassword","Account",new{id="temp"})" id=" lnk"> ForgotMyPassword</a>
```

and here is my JQuery code that I found in a forum for dynamically passing the value of text box to the Url.Action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#lnk").click(function (evt) {
        var temporary= $("#lnk").prop("href");
        var uri = temporary.replace("temp", $("#Username").val());
    });
</script>
```

The Scenario is if user doesn't remember the password, he types his username and clicks on the link and goes to password recovery page. My problem is that the value it sends is always temp and not the textbox value. How can I fix it and if there is any better approach, I'll be glad to hear it.

Update:This is my entire form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin", role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @Html.Label("username")
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "username" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "display:block;margin-top:3px;" })
                    @Html.Label("pass")
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <a href="@Url.Action("ForgotPassword","Account",new{id="temp"})" id=" lnk">forgot my password</a>
                    <input type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
                }
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this at all? Why can't they type their username in on the forgotten password screen - in a secure form post - instead of passing it around insecurely in the URL? In this context, privacy is more important than usability.

Comment: Take a look into http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset#reset

Comment: This is the scenario And I should do like this and the second reason is because in the password recovery page we load the security questions for the user that we typed in the in this page and after that he answered the questions correctly, the password will be sent to his mobile and all of the login and password recovery works perfect except this part that this value can not be sent properly. if you have a better approach please post it.

Comment: You could either put the link into a form, or use a session value so you can dynamically modify the view(Ajax call...) . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167274/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-action-and-passing-a-parameter-from-user-input

Comment: @blacai my textbox is in a form with post method. Is This Approach Possible? And can you be more specific with ajax call? if possible show an example thanx.

Comment: @Hooman please show more code of your form. With an Ajax call you could replace a partialview with a generated link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a possible solution using the partialviews and an AJAX call
As you can see, there is a partialview inside your form. Everytime you type anything in the `Username` input it fires the event that just executes an AJAX call passing the value and replaces the partialview.

***SOLUTION 1 (partialview)***

**Your form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.Label("username")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "username" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "display:block;margin-top:3px;" })
    @Html.Label("pass")
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "password" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div id="_linkPartial">
        @Html.Partial("_linkPartial", String.Empty);
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id^="Username"]').keyup(function () {
            debugger;
            var url = '/Account/RefreshLink';
            var username = this.value;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                data: { value: username },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#_linkPartial').html(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    // handle errors
                    location.href = "/Account/"
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**_linkPartial**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ForgotPassword","Account",new{id=Model})" id=" lnk">forgot my password</a>
```

**Account Controller**

```
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string id)
{
    //whatever you want to do...

    return View();
}

public ActionResult RefreshLink(string value)
{
    return PartialView("_linkPartial", value);
}
```

***SOLUTION 2 (Replacing HREF)***

**Your form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.Label("username")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "username" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "display:block;margin-top:3px;" })
    @Html.Label("pass")
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "password" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <a href="@Url.Action("ForgotPassword","Account",new{id=""})" id="lnk">forgot my password</a>
    <input type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id^="Username"]').keyup(function () {
            debugger;
            var username = this.value;
            var linkcontrol = $("#lnk");
            var newUrl = '@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account", new { id = "_id_" })'.replace('_id_', username);
            linkcontrol.attr("href", newUrl)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Anyway, I think other solutions with isolated forms for login/forgotpassword might be better.

Comment: It may seem crazy but it doesn't work. When I build the project it gives me an error in my _linkPartial partialview. Can u do it without partialview?

Comment: Did you copy the partial view as it is? It is just a _linkPartial.cshtml file with that line insine. Nothing else.  And what is the error?

Comment: I solved the error problem in the partialview, Now I am building the the project and when I click on the forgot password link I want to set the passing  id to viewdata["u"] and send it  into forgotpassword view. Then it gives me the error that viewdata["u"] is null and when I traced the code, the passing id in the ForgotPassword action is null. Do you know what is the Problem? I think your code should work :(

Comment: Well, I updated with a second solution without using partialviews, just simply jquery. About your new problem, you should show what else you are trying to do. Your first question about how to dynamically generate an url might not be related with the new error you are getting.

Comment: I have tested both of your codes.I mean that when I use your solutions(any of them), the id that is passing is null and has no value.Therefore,I can not use them in my ForgotPassword Action.

Comment: Could you show your action method? Because I am testing it and the ForgotPassword Action gets the id perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84895/discussion-between-hooman-and-blacai).